# How do you run a SCL file in MPLAB without a "Run SCL" button

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab, adc

I have an assembly code for PIC18F458 that gets data from channel 0 (RA0) of ADC and displays the result on PORTC and PORTD.

Therefore, I am trying to stimulate the RA0 pin on a PIC18F458 using a SCL file in the MPLAB X V5.05 Stimulus window.

Although, the file is successfully attached (see Image 1); when I run the simulation, there is no way of confirming if the SCL is actually being ran, aside from the ADRESL and ADRESH regsiters not containing any values (see image 2).

[image: Simulator Window without Run SCL button]

**Simulator Window without Run SCL button**

[image: No data in ADRESH and ADRESL registers]

**No data in ADRESH and ADRESL registers**

Additionally, I do not have a "Run SCL" button; unlike the other examples that I have seen online. (Please see image 1 above)

UPDATE:

Slightly modifying the examples provided by @Kozmotronik, I have been able to confirm that the SCL file is running and the injection of data onto the AIO pin. Therefore, this particular question can now be considered closed!!

Comment: Perhaps some additional details would help to analyze the situation and maybe we give it a try using MPLAB simulator. For example what version of MPLAB do you use and what PIC is it? You could also include the values in your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research in [SCL Code Repo](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m109149.aspx) and SCL User's guide that is provided within MPLAB IDE help, and also after some test, I couldn't manage to get values from a file even with a direct SCL code. The SCL code I used first is the following:

```vhdl
configuration for "pic18f458" is
end configuration;

testbench for "pic18f458" is
begin
    // Register Injection
    process is
    file fileVar : text;
    variable status : file_open_status;
    variable val : integer;
    begin
        report("Analog injection started...");
        file_open(status, fileVar, "<data_file_path>", read_mode);
        if status == open_ok then
            report("Reading the values file...");
            while endfile(fileVar) == false loop
                read(fileVar, val);
                wait until ADCON0.GO_nDONE == '1';
                report("Conversion started");
                wait until ADCON0.GO_nDONE == '0';
                report("Conversion ended");
                if ADCON1.ADFM == '0' then  -- left justified
                    ADRESH <= val / 4;
                    ADRESL <= val * 64;
                else                        -- right justified
                    ADRESH <= val / 256;
                    ADRESL <= val;
                end if;
            end loop;
        file_close(fileVar);
        wait;
        end if;
    end process;

end testbench;
```

I did saw the report strings in the simulator output but the ADRES registers are always injected with *0xFFFF* value. I tried modified versions with no success.

---

However, when I decided to modify the SCL code and give it a try with an in-code variable it did worked. The values of the in-code variable were injected correctly. From this case I figured out that the file read operation fails in somewhere and can't get the value from the file correctly. The latter working SCL code is the following:

```vhdl
configuration for "pic18f458" is
end configuration;

testbench for "pic18f458" is
begin
    // Register Injection
    process is
    file fileVar : text;
    variable status : file_open_status;
    variable val : integer;
    begin
        report("Analog injection started...");
        val := 7;
        while val < 1024 loop
            wait until ADCON0.GO_nDONE == '1';
            report("Conversion started");
            wait until ADCON0.GO_nDONE == '0';
            report("Conversion ended");
            if ADCON1.ADFM == '0' then  -- left justified
                ADRESH <= val / 4;
                ADRESL <= val * 64;
            else                        -- right justified
                ADRESH <= val / 256;
                ADRESL <= val;
            end if;
            val := val * 8;
        end loop;
        report("Analog injection ended...");
        wait;
    end process;

end testbench;
```

The above SCL code will inject the actual value of the `val` variable everytime an ADC conversion ends (GO_nDONE bit first goes high and when the conversion is completed goes low). The value injection is made depending on the `ADFM` bit. if it is set to 0 the value will be left justified, otherwise will be right justified.

So I have posted [an issue](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1224159.aspx) in the microchip forums regarding this matter. Let's see how it will be resolved.

---

Well if the values need not to be very specific you can make use of the second SCL code. However, in order to enable register injection in MPLABX IDE you need to configure the simulator first. To do this

1. Open the project properties window by clicking **File -> Project Properties** in the menu.
2. Then from categories section select **Simulator**.
3. Select **Periph: ADC1** from the **Option categories** in the right pane.
4. Finally make sure that **Use MPLAB 8 Style Stimulus/SCL for ADCxBUF0** is checked as in the following image.

[image]

Once you've configured it open the stimulus window, first start the simulation once so that it shows its content and then click on **Attach SCL file** icon to attach your SCL file and finally restart the simulation with the newly attached SCL.

---

#### UPDATE

I just simplified [this](https://www.microchip.com/forums/FindPost/112987) example from the [SCL repository](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m109149.aspx) and boom it works!

What I change in the code is; I was reading from the text file directly into the SCL variable which gives me no success, with the help of the SCL repo example, I created a line variable called dline, I read from a file into the dline using readline() builtin function, then I read from dline into the val variable using the read() function which resulted with success. The ADRES registers did injected with the correct values by each reading. Here is the updated code:

```vhdlconfiguration
end configuration;

testbench for "pic18f458" is
begin
    // Register Injection
    process is
    file fileVar : text;
    variable status : file_open_status;
    variable dline : line;
    variable val : integer;
    begin
        report("Analog injection started...");
        file_open(status, fileVar, "<data_file_path>", read_mode);
        if status == open_ok then
            report("Reading the values file...");
            while endfile(fileVar) == false loop
                wait until ADCON0.GO_nDONE == '1';
                readline(fileVar, dline);
                read(dline, val);
                report("Conversion started");
                wait until ADCON0.GO_nDONE == '0';
                report("Conversion ended");
                if ADCON1.ADFM == '0' then  -- left justified
                    ADRESH <= val / 4;
                    ADRESL <= val * 64;
                else                        -- right justified
                    ADRESH <= val / 256;
                    ADRESL <= val;
                end if;
            end loop;
        file_close(fileVar);
        wait;
        end if;
    end process;

end testbench;
```

Here is the data file. Note that the values are separated with new lines:

```
1
3
7
15
31
63
127
255
511
755
927
1023
1015
988
775
550
285
137
79
47
24
12
5
1
```

Comment: 1. Have you set the data file path correctly? 2. Note that the values will be injected just after the `GO_nDONE` bit becomes 0. Do you set that bit to start convertion and see that it changes to 0? Tell me the implementation steps. Because the SCL depends on the `GO_nDONE` bit state.

Comment: Yes, everything seems to be working, aside from the values being saved into the ADRESH and ADRESL registers. They are instead saved into file register locations, for both the hard-coded value and those read in from the text file.

Comment: It's weird. It actually writes to 0xFD8 which corresponds to the `STATUS` register in the SFR memory map. Can you restart the MPLAB IDE and retry the simulation? I recommend you to watch the ADRES register as 16 bit in the variables window.

Comment: Thanks. I will take your suggestions onboard and give both of them a try. Will feedback soon.

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment about the values being saved into file register locations. Those values are not relevant to this discussion and I apologise for the confusion. I have to modified the SCL file so that values are now being saved in the ADRES registers. However, it's just churning out the same values that is being fed into the pin. But that's something for me to look in.